# Man chained to a gold Inca-style shield and wandering desert

Tags: story-identification

Watched in UK in about 1991.  Mexico? desert.  Cowboy-ish, contemporary as a pick up truck arrives in last scene.  Totally bizarre, a man is chained to a gold Inca style shield and wanders desert, thirsty and eats dust out of a skull.  Little dialogue.

Well guys, it kind of starts with a group of cowboy types in a shoot out in ruined building, i am unsure, a woman is involved. Then goes weird as the main character is chained to this metre wide Inca gold shield...i think it was stolen and for what seems like an hour he drags it round the desrt.  It was on TV.  It has bugged me and I have googled it a million ways but no luck.  They didn't speak much in it at all and I reckon it was foreign. Cheers!

Comment: could you please be a little more descriptive?

Comment: Watched at a cinema, or on TV?

Comment: What about this was science fiction or fantasy?

Comment: Sounds a bit like scenes from "Sahara", but they were chained to the bed liner of a pickup truck, not an Incan shield. The timing's also a good decade or so off.

Comment: Watched on TV in 1990 in UK.  Assume film is older.  Still looking today in 2023.  It was like a spaghetti western?  Fantasy.  Thanks 